# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/transaction/interceptor/TransactionInterceptor Error

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-transactions

I'm trying to configure `<tx:annotation-driven  />`   in web.xml under a tomcat project using tomcat 6 and postgresql 9.1

My dispacher-Servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans  xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
        xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
        xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
        xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
        xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.1.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd        
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd">

    <mvc:default-servlet-handler/>
    <mvc:resources  mapping="/css/**" location="/css/" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="Controllers" /> 
    <context:component-scan base-package="DAOModel" />
    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <bean id="viewResolver"
          class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
          p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp/"
          p:suffix=".jsp" />

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/car" />
        <property name="username" value="postgres" />
        <property name="password" value="123" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="annotatedClasses">
            <list>
                <value>DAOModel.Tblusers</value>
                <value>DAOModel.Tblcars</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="DAOModel" />
        <!-- <property name="configurationClass" value="org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration" /> -->
    </bean>
    <tx:annotation-driven  />
    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

And :

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/transaction/interceptor/TransactionInterceptor
    org.springframework.transaction.config.AnnotationDrivenBeanDefinitionParser$AopAutoProxyConfigurer.configureAutoProxyCreator(AnnotationDrivenBeanDefinitionParser.java:126)
    org.springframework.transaction.config.AnnotationDrivenBeanDefinitionParser.parse(AnnotationDrivenBeanDefinitionParser.java:84)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.NamespaceHandlerSupport.parse(NamespaceHandlerSupport.java:73)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1419)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1409)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:184)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.doRegisterBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:140)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.registerBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:111)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:493)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:390)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:334)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:302)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:174)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:209)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:180)
    org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:125)
    org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:94)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:131)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:522)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:436)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:631)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:588)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:645)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:508)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:449)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:133)
    javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:212)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:859)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

Comment: and exists spring-tx-3.1.1.jar in web-inf\lib

Comment: if my answer is heplful you can select my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A NoClassDef error is generally when you do have the class during compile time but it isn't present during runtime. 
Please check your maven dependencies thoroughly for any jar conflicts. This might be a possible cause for the NoClassDef.
Check your pom.xml and navigate to the dependency hierarchy tab to verify if you do not see the same jar with different versions twice.

If you do have jar conflicts you would have to remove one of them based on your requirement of using the specific version

You can also alternatively check your dependency tree through the command line.

For example, to find out why Commons Collections 2.0 is being used by the Maven Dependency Plugin, we can execute the following in the project's directory:

```
mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose -Dincludes=commons-collections
```

Here is the official [Maven dependency plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/resolving-conflicts-using-the-dependency-tree.html)

### EDIT : Straight from the Maven dependency plugin page. I thought it would make the answer more descriptive rather than clicking several links.

A very good example shown on the official page about resolving-conflicts-using-the-dependency-tree

For example, to find out why Commons Collections 2.0 is being used by the Maven Dependency Plugin, we can execute the following in the project's directory:

```
mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose -Dincludes=commons-collections

The verbose flag instructs the dependency tree to display conflicting dependencies that were omitted from the resolved dependency tree. In this case, the goal outputs:

[INFO] [dependency:tree]
[INFO] org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:maven-plugin:2.0-alpha-5-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- org.apache.maven.reporting:maven-reporting-impl:jar:2.0.4:compile
[INFO] |  \- commons-validator:commons-validator:jar:1.2.0:compile
[INFO] |     \- commons-digester:commons-digester:jar:1.6:compile
[INFO] |        \- (commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:2.1:compile - omitted for conflict with 2.0)
[INFO] \- org.apache.maven.doxia:doxia-site-renderer:jar:1.0-alpha-8:compile
[INFO]    \- org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-velocity:jar:1.1.3:compile
[INFO]       \- commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:2.0:compile
Thus we can see that Commons Collections 2.0 was chosen over 2.1 since it is nearer, and by default Maven resolves version conflicts with a nearest-wins strategy.

More specifically, in verbose mode the dependency tree shows dependencies that were omitted for: being a duplicate of another; conflicting with another's version and/or scope; and introducing a cycle into the dependency tree.
```

Comment: updated the answer on how to check it from the command line. I am not sure on an easy way to check it from Netbeans, but this will serve your purpose

Answer (score 0):

You need to check your runtime classpath (i.e. WEB-INF/lib) for spring-tx-...jar (and make sure you have only one such jar, not many with different versions)
if jar exist there then the exceptions means either that, or that you have more than one jar containing the interceptor, which confuses the classloader

here the [link](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/o/Downloadorgspringframeworktransaction305RELEASEjar.htm) to download jar

Comment: exists only one jar file from spring-tx.jar in web-inf/lib

Comment: @user1555450 try to download latest version of jar i have edited my answer check out that link to download jar

Comment: i try to download latest version of jar But Not Work

Comment: @ATJVS have you set your classpath