# Missing JTA Dependencies with Spring-Boot 1.5.16 JBoss 6.4.X

Tags: java, spring-boot, jta, jboss6.x

I deployed the a WAR created from a spring boot 1.5.16 application to a JBoss version 6.4.20 but following problem occures:

```
2018-09-27 11:57:00,012 ERROR [org.springframework.scheduling.support.TaskUtils$LoggingErrorHandler] (pool-5-thread-1) Unexpected error occurred in scheduled task.: 
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager' defined in class path resource 
[ch/migrosbank/otv/infrastructure/database/DatabaseConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/transaction/jta/UserTransactionAdapter at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1708) 
[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE] at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:581) [spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE] at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:503) [spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE] at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317) 
[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE] at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) 
[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE] at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315) 
[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE] at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:224) 
[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE] at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveNamedBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1015) 
[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE] at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:339) 
[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE] at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:334) 
[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE] at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.determineTransactionManager(TransactionAspectSupport.java:394) 
[spring-tx-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE] at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:284) 
[spring-tx-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE] at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:98) 
[spring-tx-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE] at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185) 
[spring-aop-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE] at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:688) 
[spring-aop-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE] at ch.migrosbank.otv.infrastructure.job.RemoveNotConfirmedAppointmentsJob$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$5e5892a1.run() 
[otv-infrastructure-2.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.0.0-SNAPSHOT] at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54) 
[spring-context-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE] at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ReschedulingRunnable.run(ReschedulingRunnable.java:93) 
[spring-context-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE] at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) 
[rt.jar:1.8.0_172] at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) 
[rt.jar:1.8.0_172] at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180) 
[rt.jar:1.8.0_172] at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
[rt.jar:1.8.0_172] at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
[rt.jar:1.8.0_172] at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) 
[rt.jar:1.8.0_172] at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) 
[rt.jar:1.8.0_172] Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/transaction/jta/UserTransactionAdapter at org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager.buildUserTransaction(JtaTransactionManager.java:562) 
[spring-tx-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE] at org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager.initUserTransactionAndTransactionManager(JtaTransactionManager.java:488) 
[spring-tx-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE] at org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager.afterPropertiesSet(JtaTransactionManager.java:446) 
[spring-tx-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE] at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1767) 
[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE] at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1704) 
[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE] ... 24 more
```

As described within the spring boot documentation (https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.16.RELEASE/reference/html/boot-features-jta.html#boot-features-jta-javaee) i dont need to add any dependencies.

Datasource and Jta stuff is configured like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class DatabaseConfiguration {

  @Bean(name = "dataSource")
  public DataSource dataSourceForProd(@Value("${datasource.appointment}") final String dataSourceName) {
    return new JndiDataSourceLookup().getDataSource(dataSourceName);
  }

  @Bean(name = "transactionManager")
  public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManagerForProd() {
    return new JtaTransactionManager();
  }

  @Bean(name = "namedParameterJdbcTemplate")
  public NamedParameterJdbcTemplate namedParameterJdbcTemplate(final DataSource dataSource) {
    return new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(dataSource);
  }
}
```

Any idea what's wrong?

Comment: can you please post the whole stacktrace?

Comment: @dom this might help you.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21202005/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-org-springframework-transaction-interceptor-tran